# Javascript not operating on loaded elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to understand grid layouts so I wrote some js to recursively color each element on the page to expose each grid tile.

## The problem

Every few refreshes some of the tiles don't get colored. I figured this was some kind of loading error so instead of running the code immediately I decided to run it in `window.onload`. That didn't change anything.

I even wrote a piece of code to print the uncolored elements to the console. I run that code in the same loop where individual elements are painted and expected nothing to be logged, to my surprise the color is generated,  the element is created, and still the element remains uncolored!

## Plea

Can someone tell me what's going on here? It's not very important in this application but this goes against everything I know about how js operates, and it would be helpful to extend my understanding. Thanks!

## P.S. Demo

I added this little demo and the problem happens here too. You will need to run the code a couple times to see the error, I wrote another piece of code that prints the uncolored element to the console so you can't miss it!

```js
let colorize = (elements) => {
  for (let e of elements) {
    let color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    e.style["background-color"] = color;
    checkcolor(e, color);
    colorize(e.children);
  }
}
let checkcolor = (e, color) => {
  if (!e.style['background-color']) {
    console.log(e, color);
  }
}
window.onload = () => colorize(document.querySelector("html").children);
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 3px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(10px, 100px));
  /* grid-template-columns: 1; */
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

```html
<div>11</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>33</div>
<div>44</div>
<div>55</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of one of the `console.log` results:

```
<div>55</div> #43b0f
```

That should give you the idea - the string that was generated has only 5 characters (or fewer), not 6, so it's not a valid hex color. This will happen when the generated number has leading zeros.

One way to fix it would be to `padStart` the number with zeros:

```js
const colorize = (elements) => {
  for (let e of elements) {
    let color = '#' +
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)
      .toString(16)
      .padStart(6, '0');
    e.style["background-color"] = color;
    colorize(e.children);
  }
}
colorize(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 3px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(10px, 100px));
  /* grid-template-columns: 1; */
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

```html
<div>11</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>33</div>
<div>44</div>
<div>55</div>
```

Comment: _"...the string that was generated has only 5 characters (**or fewer**), not 6,..."_ - 3 would be also valid